# MySQL Select Join on Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables (tbldept, tblcourse, tblstud, tblviolation) and I want to extract specific values. The below tables is like the same on my tables

```
tbldept
id | dept
1  | deptA
2  | deptB
```

`tbldept` has foreign key on `tblcourse`

```
tblcourse
id | deptId | course
1  |    2     | courseA
2  |    1     | courseB
3  |    1     | courseC
```

`tblcourse` has foreign key on `tblstud`

```
tblstud
id | courseId | name 
1  |   1      | studA
2  |   2      | studB
3  |   1      | studC
```

`tblstud` has foreign key on `tblviolation`

```
tblviolation
id | studId | violationName
1  |   3    |  violationA
2  |   2    |  violationB
3  |   1    |  violationC
4  |   3    |  violationC
```

***What I want to get is look like this: ***

```
dept | studId | name   | violationName
  2  |    1   | studA  | violationC
  2  |    2   | studB  | violationB
  1  |    3   | studC  | violationA
  1  |    3   | studC  | violationC
```

I want to get all the rows of `tblviolation` for each `studId`.
I hope you guys understand what I am trying to explain. =) Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, I find the convention of sticking 'tbl' in front of everything absolutely infuriating. What's wrong with 'departments', 'students', and 'courses'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `inner join`. Try this.

```
select d.dept,s.studid,s.name,v.violationname
from tbldept d 
inner join tblcourse c
on d.id=c.deptid
inner join tblstud s
on c.id=s.courseid
inner join tblviolation v
on s.id=v.studid
```